# create children properties recursively in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, children

I am trying to create a depth of children based on a passed parameter `n`.
Basically if n is 4, the resulting object should be
`parent.children.children.children.children`.

I've come up with this so far:

```
parent = {}

function makechildren( current, depth ){
  current['children']={}
  while (depth>0){       {
    str = JSON.stringify(current)
    return makechildren(current, depth-1)
  }
}
}
makechildren(parent, 4)
```

Comment: why the minus 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code and it works

```
parent={};
var obj;
function makechildren( current, depth){
  if(depth>0) 
  {  
    current = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(current).replace('{}','{"children":{}}'))
    makechildren(current, depth-1);
  }else{
    obj = current;
    return ;
  }

}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: What's the point of using `while` if you break it in the first iteration?

Comment: @Oussama Werfelli thanks but that's not right. it prints parent.children 4 times that's all

Comment: @Whatever how so? it doesn't break it

Comment: @uniXVanXcel, `return` means "stop execution and exit the function immediately"

Comment: @Oussama Werfelli  you shoud test it it does not work, not sure why you got a +1 here..thanks though - iam trying to print `parent.children.children.children.children` not `parent.children` 4 times in a row

Comment: @Whatever its a recursive function, not sure how what you re saying helps here...

Comment: @uniXVanXcel you are wright, I edited my answer with working code, and know I deserve the +1 :D